# How to replace values in 2-D string array

Tags: c#, string, multidimensional-array

How to perform this task?

```
int Amount, x=1000,y=200;
string BasedOn="x*12/100+y*5/100";
//In place of x and y in BasedOn I want to  replace with x,y values like (1000*12%+200*5%) 
//and the calculated result(130) should be assigned to Amount variable
```

For now, I split the BasedOn string

```
string[][] strings = BasedOn
    .Split(new char[] { '+' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(w => w.Split('*').ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

What to do next? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your code more flexible

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> variables = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        variables.Add("x", 1000);
        variables.Add("y", 200);
        string equation = "x*12/100+y*5/100";
        var result = Calculate(variables, equation);
    }
    static object Calculate(Dictionary<string, object> variables, string equation)
    {
        variables.ToList().ForEach(v => equation = equation.Replace(v.Key, v.Value.ToString()));
        return new DataTable().Compute(equation, string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on the DataTable.Compute method.
It can be used like this on your case:

```
using System.Data;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var Amount = dt.Compute("1000*12%+200*5%","");
```

For replacing "x" and "y" with numeric values you can use string.Replace

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the string AND calculate the result, you can do:

```
int Amount, x=1000,y=200;
string BasedOn=$"{x}*12/100+{y}*5/100";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var v = dt.Compute(BasedOn,"");
```

v will be your result (130).

EDIT: You have to replace your %'s with division by 100, as the datatable thinks its a mod operator.

Comment: @mybirthname Fixed.

Comment: @UmutSeven getting SyntaxExceptionError(Cannot interpret token '"' at position 2) at var v = dt.Comput(BasedOn,"")

Comment: @snehanagaruru Thats weird, it works in my machine. Try `string.Empty` instead of double quotes ("")?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look NCalc (http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression):

```
int Amount, x = 1000, y = 200; string BasedOn = "x*12%+y*5%";

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("x", typeof(int));   // in Visual Studio 2015 you can use nameof(x) instead of "x"
dt.Columns.Add("y", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int), BasedOn.Replace("%", "/100")); // "x*12/100+y*5/100" ("%" is considered modulus operator)

Amount = (int)dt.Rows.Add(x, y)["Amount"];  // 130
```

---

With [`RegEx.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy) and [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute):

```
string expression = Regex.Replace(BasedOn.Replace("%", "/100"), "[a-zA-Z]+",
    m => (m.Value == "x") ? x + "" : (m.Value == "y") ? y + "" : m.Value);  // "1000*12/100+200*5/100"

Amount = (int)(double)new DataTable().Compute(expression, ""); // 130.0 (double)
```